# Give Nix SU privileges

Tags: rooting

I have a rooted device that runs our custom app in the system/priv-app folder. I would like to enable OTA updates, but would need to give SureMDM Nix app SU privileges. I am told the package name is com.nix. Does anyone know how to do this with ADB. I have root level privileges via ADB remount or SU commands.

Comment: You can't decide to give an app root privileges, if the app itself doesn't ask for them.

Comment: SureMDM wants me to give there app the ability to execute scripts as SU. SuperUser APK must be doing this. I don't want to install that app on the device. That is why I am asking.

Comment: Do system apps ask for root access?

Comment: I was thinking of moving it to the system/app folder

Answer (score 2):

Grant all required SuperSU Permissions  on one of the device and then connect it to desktop through USB and execute below commands .

**Note:** This commands will work only if adb has root access . 
          It will be good if you uncheck Re-authetication & check Trust System User option also at the time of intial configuration .

```
adb root
adb shell
chmod 777 /data/data/eu.chainfire.supersu/shared_prefs/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml;
cat data/data/eu.chainfire.supersu/shared_prefs/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml > /sdcard/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml ;
exit;
adb pull /sdcard/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml ;
```

For **replicating** above same SuperSU settings on other device, connect  device to desktop through usb and execute below commands .

```
adb push  ../eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml /sdcard/
adb root
adb shell
chmod 777 /data/data/eu.chainfire.supersu/shared_prefs/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml;
cat /sdcard/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml > data/data/eu.chainfire.supersu/shared_prefs/eu.chainfire.supersu_preferences.xml ;
am force-stop eu.chainfire.supersu;am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n eu.chainfire.supersu/.MainActivity ;
```